# Mimetype handling by chrome extension (packaged apps)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm wondering if  a file, with a given mimetype, can be handled by a packaged app.

I saw that in manifest file, the nacl_modules could be used to associate a native client module with a mimetype.

I need my packaged app  to handle desktop files with a specific mimetype.

As packaged app could be up and running without Chrome being displayed it seems possible, but the question is how !

Thanks for your advice and comments.

Guy

Comment: It seems that webintent could be used for this purpose like explained on [http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app_intents.html#launching]

Comment: The web intent feature is disabled inside Chrome at least in version 24 [https://plus.google.com/116171619992010691739/posts/gcXURKLN8bg]

Answer (score 0):

You can handle files using this manifest section:
http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/manifest.html#file_handlers

```
   "file_handlers": {
     "testhandler": {
       "title": "TestHandler",
       "types": ["*/*"]
      }
    },
   "permissions": ["fileSystem"],
```

The selected file(s) will then be passed in the launchData param of onLaunched event handler.

Notice that this is not yet available when launching from a file manager on platforms other than ChromeOS. On those platforms, it will only work now if you execute the app from the command line with the filenames as parameters (http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/first_app.html#open)