# Google warning: Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream

Tags: css, font-face

I have a warning in Google for my font-face:

**Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: ".../Content/Fonts/iconFont.ttf".**

It works even if I have this warning but I prefer avoid this warning.

Here is my declaration:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'iconFont';
     src: url('../Fonts/iconFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('../Fonts/iconFont.svg#iconFont') format('image/svg+xml'), 
     url('../Fonts/iconFont.woff') format('font/x-woff'), 
     url('../Fonts/iconFont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I already search on other posts but no luck so far.

Please note that my server is IIS from Microsoft.

Any idea how can I avoid this warning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

another approach on here: http://zduck.com/2013/google-chrome-and-woff-font-mime-type-warnings/

use below settings on your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff"/>
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 87):

You need to add the following types to an .htaccess/IIS:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/font-woff .woff
```

**Updated .woff type from:**

```
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
```

(Thanks to @renadeen in comments below for pointing this out.)

Check out my answer to a similar question here: [Font Face not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287465/font-face-not-loaded/14287894#14287894)

Taken from here: [font-face problem in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051826/font-face-problem-in-chrome).

Comment: I added these 4 lines at the end of my file, but I still get the error. How long does it take to make this working?

Comment: Did you try resetting/restarting your web server? IIS? Have you checked out the 2 links in my answer too?

Comment: I'm not using a web server - how can you fix this without one?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5142316/907467) `application/x-font-woff` became `application/font-woff`.

Answer (score 46):

Thanks for the above answer @97ldave, you can add these types to your IIS webServer configuration section if you'd rather not add them directly to your MIME types in your IIS setup. The following shows an example of adding just the .woff type that was missing from our configuration. This fixed the issues with the fonts not appearing in the latest version of Safari (6.0.3) on my iMac.

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Thanks to Jon Samwell (my colleague) for finding this out.

Comment: I guess that [the comment on the currently accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521130/google-warning-resource-interpreted-as-font-but-transferred-with-mime-type-appl#comment26019030_15522254) regarding removing the `x-` from the mime type is applicable to this answer as well.

Comment: Thanks! I've also added these two lines based on your answer (Semantic-UI uses it) <remove fileExtension=".woff**2**" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff**2**" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />

Answer (score 26):

For Nginx: (Path: /etc/nginx/mime.types)

```
font/ttf                         ttf;
font/otf                         otf;
application/x-font-woff          woff;
```

You dont need `application/vnd.ms-fontobject          eot;`
because it exists already.

After that restart Nginx: `service nginx restart`

Done.

Comment: No problem mate :). | If you get the warning with font-awesome(http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), just put this in your Nginx Mime Type File: application/x-font-woff .woff

Answer (score 10):

Correct MIME types for fonts are:

```
application/font-ttf              ttf;
application/font-otf              otf;
application/font-woff             woff;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you run a server with nodeJS, this is a nice module to map your mime types

https://github.com/broofa/node-mime

```
var mime = require('mime');

mime.lookup('/path/to/file.txt');         // => 'text/plain'
mime.lookup('file.txt');                  // => 'text/plain'
mime.lookup('.TXT');                      // => 'text/plain'
mime.lookup('htm');                       // => 'text/html'

mime.extension('text/html');                 // => 'html'
mime.extension('application/octet-stream');  // => 'bin'
```

Comment: I added the essentials

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @the-senator and @97ldave for their answers

for me the error completely disappear just after adding these lines to the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```