# Font not rendering/displaying as expected

Tags: fonts, font-face, photoshop

I am having an issue with a font. It renders as expected in Microsoft Word but not in either Photoshop or when I install it as a custom font using @font-face.

I can see from Chrome inspect tools>computed styles that it is rendering the said font but it isn't rendering correctly. I have re-installed, downloaded from a different source, tried different font formats. It also renders correctly in my browser on the demo html file that came with the font from one of the websites. I would have posted a screen shot but I can't due to less than 10 rep.

I have tried to work out what it is but to no avail, sure it's something obvious though!

Here is a link to the font: [Font source](http://www.fonts2u.com/foglihtenno01.font)

Any help greatly appreciated. I am using Chrome and Photoshop CS3.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your css look like?

Comment: check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521130/google-warning-resource-interpreted-as-font-but-transferred-with-mime-type-appl/15522254#15522254 and the links in the answer. Looks like it may be related.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the anti-aliasing method to smooth, it can be found beside(right-side) the font size(while having the type tool)