# @font-face is not working on OS X Yosemite Chrome 26 - versions

Tags: css, font-face, osx-yosemite

My font is not working on OS X Yosemite Chrome 26 - versions. It shows blank space in the place of the font. In latest browser versions font works fine.

CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DIN-Regular';
  src: url('fonts/DIN-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('fonts/DIN-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('fonts/DIN-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('fonts/DIN-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('fonts/DIN-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('fonts/DIN-Regular.svg#svgDIN-Regular') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Edit:

```
body {
  font-family: 'DIN-Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

The fonts after comma are not working too

Can anyone help?

Comment: "In latest browser versions font works fine." - by this do you mean newer versions of Chrome too? Or does it not work in Chrome at  all?

Comment: yes, in Chrome 40, 39.. works fine, only old versions have problems with font

Comment: are you sure there isn't a different CSS issue occurring here? Does nay text appear? or is the font just not applying?

Comment: no, text is just disappeared, not sure which can be a problem, as no problematic styles are on it. just font-size, color, line-height.., other fonts are working only with "DIN-Regular" font this happens.

Comment: can you give a demo of it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem was in font files generated by font generators.

The fonts generated from:

https://www.web-font-generator.com/ ,

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator ,....

don't work properly in Chrome old versions.

Finally, I've found another one: https://fontie.flowyapps.com/home , by which generated font types work fine in all browser versions.

Thanks all for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the font in your CSS?

```
body {
font-family: 'DIN-Regular', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: yes, the problem is that all this wants are not working (fonts after comma), but when I give only Arial, it shows the font

Comment: Open your control panel, are there any 404 errors?  Maybe it is a pathing issue to the fonts folder?

Comment: If that were a path issue fonts would not work at all, but in latest version of Chrome it works fine.

Comment: @FrontDev `If that were a path issue fonts would not work at all` thats not fully true. While unlikely in this particular case, in theory the versions around 26 could e.g. try  `.ttf` first if available and then before using `.woff` or anything similar, thats why the hit to check a `404` is not absurd. But I think the MIME problem mentioned in the other answer is more likely the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

> Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type
>   application/octet-stream

To solve this issue, check out my answer here: [Google warning: Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521130/google-warning-resource-interpreted-as-font-but-transferred-with-mime-type-appl)

You need to add mime type to htaccess/IIS:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/font-woff .woff
```

Comment: Added Mime types in htaccess but no success :(

Comment: The image I have posted in my answer is why your font is not displaying. So there is a good starting point. I had the same problem and it was due to mime types.